# How to parse a log using some keys - Python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following check_status method:

```
def check_status(self):
    # each of these is a process I want to make sure they are running.
    status = {
        'pm' : False,
        'om' : False,
        'dm' : False,
        'redis' : False,
    }
    cmd = "sudo %s/foo status" % config.FOO_TOOLS
    output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
    print output
    for k, v in status.iteritems():
        print k
```

I want to parse `output` based on the keys of `status`, and if one of them is `Not running` I can attempt to restart. I want to do it based on the a regex. 
Here is an example when the processes are not running:

```
[WARN] :  current build mode : debug
app: USER PID %CPU %MEM VSZ RSS TTY STAT START TIME COMMAND
pm : Not running
om : Not running
dm : Not running
```

Conversely, here's an example when the processes are running:

```
[WARN] :  current build mode : debug
app: USER PID %CPU %MEM VSZ RSS TTY STAT START TIME COMMAND
pm : root 12337 0.0 0.2 455920 9664 [more crap here]
om : root 12383 0.7 3.1 3256848 114936 [more crap here]
dm : root 12516 11.7 0.4 930316 15508 [more crap here]
[INFO] :  redis [pid=5349] running @ [port:6379]
```

How can I parse `output` based on the existing key?

Comment: You should edit post and add data that is replaced by `[more crap here]`. Also, did you try reading docs about regular expressions?

Comment: @AndrewDunai I added `[more crap here]` because that's not important to the problem. And yes, I read and I'm reading docs about regular expressions, but I'm just not sure how to obtain that exact parse I'm looking for ...

Comment: and you want to parse it in Python, right?

Comment: @AndrewDunai Yes sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can process the output line by line looking for information you want. The output has a couple of sections but its simple enough that you can brute force it without the code being too ugly.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
# skip [WARN]
proc.stdout.readline()
# look for interesting data in remaining
for line in proc.stdout:
    # terminate after processing the [INFO] section
    if line.startswith('[INFO] :  redis'):
        status['redis'] = True
        for line in proc.stdout:
            pass
        break
    # get the process status
    name, remaining = line.split(' ', 1):
    if name in status:
        status[name] = not 'Not running' in remaining
proc.wait()
```

Comment: Just a comment, this line doesn't work: `if name in self.status` ... that's always false.

Comment: Strange, it should work. Add `print "%s starts with '%s'" % (line.strip(), name)` right before the check to see if we are looking at the right stuff. Also, you said `self.status` - are we looking at two status dicts?

Comment: `pm : root 14240 0.0 0.2 455920 7648 pts/7 Sl 14:38 0:00starts with 'pm'`

Comment: Trimming your status dict down a bit, that's `status={'pm': False};'pm' in status` which is True. Perhaps printing `self.status.keys()` will give us a hint.

Comment: `self.status.keys()=['om', 'dm', 'redis', 'am', 'sm', 'pm']`

Comment: I found: `'\x1b[0;33mapp:'` that's they string I got ... but why?

Comment: Its giving you colored output (`\x1b[0;33m` is an escape sequence to turn on brown) but it shouldn't because you are redirecting output to a pipe. Is there an option to not colorize?